# Trying to write a script to clean <script.aa=([].slice+'hjkbghkj') from multiple htm files, recursively

Tags: bash

I am trying to modify a bash script to remove a glob of malicious code from a large number of files.

The community will benefit from this, so here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash

grep -r -l 'var createDocumentFragm' /home/user/Desktop/infected_site/* > /home/user/Desktop/filelist.txt

for i in $(cat /home/user/Desktop/filelist.txt)
do
   cp -f $i $i.bak
done

for i in $(cat /home/user/Desktop/filelist.txt)
do
   $i | sed 's/createDocumentFragm.*//g' > $i.awk
   awk '/<\/SCRIPT>/{p=1;print}/<\/script>/{p=0}!p'
```

This is where the script bombs out with this message:

```
+ for i in '$(cat /home/user/Desktop/filelist.txt)'    
+ sed 's/createDocumentFragm.*//g'    
+ /home/user/Desktop/infected_site/index.htm
```

I get 2 errors and the script stops.

```
/home/user/Desktop/infected_site/index.htm: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `<'    
/home/user/Desktop/infected_site/index.htm: line 1: `<html><head><script>(function (){ '
```

I have the first 2 parts done.

The files containing createDocumentfragm have been enumerated in a text file correctly.

The files in the textfile.txt have been duplicated, in their original location with a .bak added to them IE: infected_site/some_directory/infected_file.htm and infected_file.htm.bak
effectively making sure we have a backup.

All I need to do now is write an AWK command that will use the list of files in filelist.txt, use the entire glob of malicious text as a pattern, and remove it from the files. Using just the uppercase script as the starting point, and the lower case script is too generic and could delete legitimate text

I suspect this may help me, but I don't know how to use it correctly.

http://backreference.org/2010/03/13/safely-escape-variables-in-awk/

Once I have this part figured out, and after you have verified that the files weren't mangled you can do this to clean out the bak files:

```
for i in $(cat /home/user/Desktop/filelist.txt)
do
   rm -f $i.bak
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Several things:

You have:

```
$i | sed 's/var createDocumentFragm.*//g' > $i.awk
```

You should probably meant this (using your use of `cat` which we'll talk about in a moment):

```
cat $i | sed 's/var createDocumentFragm.*//g' > $i.awk
```

You're treating each file in your file list as if it was a command and not a file.

Now, about your use of `cat`. If you're using `cat` for almost anything but concatenating multiple files together, you probably are doing something not quite right. For example, you could have done this:

```
sed 's/var createDocumentFragm.*//g' "$i" > $i.awk
```

I'm also a bit confused about the `awk` statement. Exactly what file are you using awk on? Your `awk` statement is using STDIN and STDOUT, so it's reading file names from the for loop and then printing the output on the screen. Is the `sed` statement suppose to feed into the `awk` statement?

Note that I don't have to print out my file to STDOUT, then pipe that into sed. The `sed` command can take the file name directly.

You also want to avoid `for` loops over a list of files. That is very inefficient, and can cause problems with the command line getting overloaded. Not a big issue today, but can affect you when you least suspect it. What happens is that your `$(cat /home/user/Desktop/filelist.txt)` must execute first before the `for` loop can even start.

A little rewriting of your program:

```
cd ~/Desktop
grep -r -l 'var createDocumentFragm' infected_site/* > filelist.txt

while read file
do
     cp -f "$file" "$file.bak"
     sed 's/var createDocumentFragm.*//g' "$file" > "$i.awk"
     awk '/<\/SCRIPT>/{p=1;print}/<\/script>/{p=0}!p'
done < filelist.txt
```

We can use one loop, and we made it a while loop. I could even feed the grep into that while loop:

```
grep -r -l 'var createDocumentFragm' infected_site/* | while read file
do
     cp -f "$file" "$file.bak"
     sed 's/var createDocumentFragm.*//g' "$file" > "$i.awk"
     awk '/<\/SCRIPT>/{p=1;print}/<\/script>/{p=0}!p'
done < filelist.txt
```

and then I don't even have to create a temporary file.

Let me know what's going on with the awk. I suspect you wanted something like this:

```
grep -r -l 'var createDocumentFragm' infected_site/* | while read file
do
     cp -f "$file" "$file.bak"
     sed 's/var createDocumentFragm.*//g' "$file" \
         | awk '/<\/SCRIPT>/{p=1;print}/<\/script>/{p=0}!p' > "$i.awk"
done < filelist.txt
```

Also note I put quotes around file names. This helps prevent problems if file name has a space in it.

Comment: I may have found another possible answer, located here: [link]http://backreference.org/2010/03/13/safely-escape-variables-in-awk/ With the ability to tell AWK to use the **entire malicious glob**, regardless of ANY variable contained within, i should be able to safely remove the malicious text. I lack the necessary skill to create such a script though... :(

Comment: OP put some comments for you here: http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/239391